# Strophe.attach not working - I am using openfire locally

Tags: openfire, strophe

I am trying to implment the XMPP Client. I am using BOSH Connection manager and can run the Strophe.connect but not Strophe.Attach. I have tried incrementing the RID, but no effect.. Any help please ? There is no error here, but the Strophe.Status.CONNECTED is never reached via the attach method and so I cannot send IQ or Presence.

Here is my code
try
{

```
    var cookieJid = $.cookie("jid");
    var cookieSid = $.cookie("sid");
    var cookieRid = $.cookie("rid");

    var connt = new Strophe.Connection("http://localhost:7070/http-bind/");

    connt.attach(cookieJid, cookieSid, cookieRid + 1, function(status)
    {

        if (status === Strophe.Status.CONNECTED)
        { 
            alert ("hola connected");
            $("#userName").append("hola connected :  " + connt.jid );

            var iq = $iq({type: 'get'}).c('query', {xmlns: 'jabber:iq:roster'});
            connt.sendIQ(iq, handleRoster);
            connt.send($pres());
        }
    });

}
catch (e)
{
    $("#userName").append("Pinky error is " + e);

}
```

**Edit**

Thanks Eric and Charlie.

So I took the latest Strophe.js and now Attached status does work.
But the connection disconnects instantaneously. I am not even able to fetch the Roster.

We can possibly do every thing with Connection.attach() as we would with connection.connect(), right?

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Change the line:

if (status === Strophe.Status.CONNECTED)

...to...

if (status === Strophe.Status.CONNECTED || status === Strophe.Status.ATTACHED)

Comment: No luck Eric. Is there really a status like Strophe.Status.ATTACHED ? Also I tried using both, full JID and bare JID. We should really be using the bare JID for Strophe.attach(), right?

Answer (score 1):

Are you using the latest Strophe library? In the version I'm using, I see that the status can be these values:

```
Status: {
    ERROR: 0,
    CONNECTING: 1,
    CONNFAIL: 2,
    AUTHENTICATING: 3,
    AUTHFAIL: 4,
    CONNECTED: 5,
    DISCONNECTED: 6,
    DISCONNECTING: 7,
    ATTACHED: 8
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you convert your cookieRid to a Number by using new Number(cookieRid).  Otherwise, when you do +1 on it, you will get "####1".

You can test this out for yourself in Javascript:

```
var s = "123";

alert(s+1); // "1231" and not "124"
```

Also, as Eric answered, there is a status ATTACHED so you need to handle that event.

Comment: Thanks Eric and Charlie.

So I took the latest Strophe.js and now Attached status does work. But the connection disconnects instantaneously. I am not even able to fetch the Roster.

We can possibly do every thing with Connection.attach() as we would with connection.connect(), right?

Any thoughts?

Comment: Are you using IE or FF?  If FF, what version?  I've found that .attach() doesn't work in FF4 at all while it works fine in IE.  There's a ticket for it in github: https://github.com/metajack/strophejs/issues/50

Comment: I am using IE.. I think.. as written by Mr Jack Moffit in his book, I need a Connection Manager like Punjab to attach a connection.. I tried a little but could not install Punjab.. I am having high time running the command 'twistd -f punjab.tac' What is "twisted" and why do I need that to run punjab ? Can somebody please provide steps to run Punjab on windows ?

Comment: You don't strictly need a connection manager to attach to a session.  You DO need to establish a session FIRST.  Depending on how you've set up your authentication on your XMPP server, you may be able to do that on the server side before you serve your page.  I'm using Openfire with LDAP authentication to AD.  We've written a custom ActiveX control (FF/Chrome users have to log in) that automatically authenticates the user using NTLM when the page loads, creates a session, and then I attach to the session using the cached JID+RID+SID.